# How to Retrieve a Date Input to filter through by Dates with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I am trying to select a date input, and use that input to filter out specific notes that were created on that date.  My date format is '2023-08-14' in my db.json files for these notes and the input format I believe is the same...I compare this values in the filter function.

The problem is that nothing is getting added to the filtered array, and I believe it is because the input is not being assigned to dateField.  I tried to console.log the value but it is undefined.  Any reason to why it is not being saved?
My files are below:
TS File:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Note } from '../note/notes';
import { NoteService } from '../note/notes.service';
//import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit{
  
  allNotes: Note[] = [];
  filteredNote: Note[] = [];
  dateField: '';
 
  constructor(private service: NoteService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    //retrieve all notes from NotesService

     this.service.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
     this.filteredNote = this.filterDate(data);
     //console.log(this.filteredNote)
     })
  }

  filterDate(data){
    console.log(this.dateField);
    //console.log("here")
    //find the one with the matching value from "date" input
    return data.filter(_ => _.date == this.dateField);
  }

}
```

html File:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <label for="start">Find a Note from Date Created:</label>
    <body>
          
        <label>
            Enter the Date:
            <input type="date" name="date" [(ngModel)]="dateField">
            <br>
        </label>
    </body>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Body</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let note of filteredNote">
                <th scope="row">{{ note.id }}</th>
                <th>{{ note.title }}</th>
                <th>{{ note.body }}</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation only filters the notes returned by the service once, so the user won't have a chance to change the value of `dateField`. It may help to bind to declare an event handler bound `(change)` to filter. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

Answer (score 0):

Introduce **ngModelChange** so that whenever user changes the input filterDate function is triggered.

```
    <label>
        Enter the Date:
        <input type="date" name="date" [(ngModel)]="dateField" (ngModelChange)="filterDate($event)" >
        <br>
    </label>
```

Taking enirre json on ngOnInit and whenever a user changes the datefield filtering wil be done.

```
 completeData:any[]=[];
  ngOnInit(){
    //retrieve all notes from NotesService

     this.service.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
     this.completeData=data;
     })
  }

  filterDate(changeddate:any){
    this.filteredNote = this.completeData.filter(_ => _.date == changeddate);
  }
```